# What permission do I need to add an HP printer with hp-setup?

Tags: permissions, printing

I try to install my printer using the following command:

```
hp-setup 10.2.1.99
```

As you might expect my printer has the IP 10.2.1.99. It is a HP Color LaserJet 2700n.

Everything works well until the very last step when I have chosen the PPD file and clicked Add Printer. I then get prompted with a box where I can write Username and Password, and the text:

> You do not have permission to add a printer

I've tried entering credentials to all accounts I can think of that exists in our office, but it does not seem to work.

If I press cancel when prompted, I get this text in the console:

> Printer queue setup failed. Could not connect to CUPS Server.  Is user added to "lpadmin" group(s)

What permission is it that I need?

Comment: It might be requesting Admin credentials (root name and password). Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes i have done that.

Answer (score 4):

Add your user to the `lp` user group. Use the following command to accomplish the task:

```
# gpasswd -a [user] lp
```

Read the ArchWiki article on [Users and Groups](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Users_and_Groups) for more information on how Groups are used for access to certain system hardware.

Turns out there are multiple bugs on Launchpad regarding this issue. These may help:
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/802780
 https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/718092
 https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/161346

Comment: Did this for both lp and lpadmin but did not seem to help. Do I need to restart some service too?

Comment: Check your config files. One user previously had the same error, while the actual problem was in /etc/cups/client.conf. This is a open bug on launchpad

Comment: Fixed my client.conf and restarted cups. I now get "Printer queue setup failed." Could not connect to CUPS Server.

Comment: Try rebooting the machine once if possible. This is to make sure the user is granted all access privileges that it is entitled to because of its groups.

Comment: Add the same problem and after I added the lp and lpadmin group to the user and rebooted the computer, it automatically started to print the queue.

Answer (score 3):

I needed:

```
sudo hp-setup
```

Adding myself to the `lp` group + logout + login did not work.

Tested on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 1):

You plugged in your printer with USB. 
Then restart your machine.

Normally it is sufficient to use this command without sudo
(hplip package is installed) :

```
hp-setup
```

You concluded the setup. Normally this should be sufficient.

With hplip then cups is not necessary.

You might use lpadmin command as described here, only when cups is needed :

https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1672833