# Ubuntu asks for permission to add a printer, but nothing works

Tags: permissions, printing, hp, authentication

I am trying to install my HP LaserJet Pro 400 color m451nw, got it all worked out using the hplip open-source program (hplip-3.14.6) until I get to the very end where I verify and setup the device and then press "Add Printer"

I then get prompted with a box where I can write Username and Password, and the text:

`You do not have permission to add a printer`

I've tried entering credentials to all accounts I can think of but it does not seem to work.

If I press cancel when prompted, I get this text in the console:

```
Printer queue setup failed.  
Error: client-error-not-authenticated
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: Run the setup program with root privileges. Type `sudo` at the beginning.

Comment: Did you add your user account to the `lpadmin` group? Check with `id -Gn` or `getent group lpadmin`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What permission do I need to add a printer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/168825/what-permission-do-i-need-to-add-a-printer)